# What is the font for beanstalkapp logo?

Tags: font-identification

I love the font for [beanstalkapp logo](http://beanstalkapp.com/):

[image: Example image]

Does someone know the font used to make that logo?  I used [whatthefont.com](http://whatthefont.com) but it could not pick up the font from the image.

Answer (score 9):

It's Cocon Pro Offc Regular by Evert Bloemsma/FontFont and it has a large family that you can use too. You can buy it at [FontShop](https://www.fontshop.com/families/ff-cocon/). You can enter "Beanstalk" in the textbox on he website to compare it to the logo.